# Stages of Life according to Buddhism

Tags: modern-world, teaching, daily-life

Like in [Hinduism](http://hinduism.about.com/od/basics/p/fourstages.htm), is there any teaching on the *stages of life* in Buddhism ?

*P.S. Answers for this question will be great "Dhamma gifts" for my upcoming Birth day.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There really isn't anything quite like [ashrama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashrama_(stage)) in Buddhism, at least as it applies to an individual person's life. Buddhism takes a simple view that one is born, lives, and then dies, within a cycle of [saṃsāra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sa%E1%B9%83s%C4%81ra) (a belief shared with Hinduism). Within the context of that life, one is either [awakened](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enlightenment_in_Buddhism) or one isn't.

I think it's interesting, since Buddhism defines many other "stages" involving *aspects* of life (just not about life itself):

- [Four stages of enlightenment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_stages_of_enlightenment)
- [Stages along the path to liberation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_Paths_to_liberation#Tibetan_Buddhism) (in Tibetan Buddhism)
- [Jhāna stages of meditation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhy%C4%81na_in_Buddhism#Qualities_of_the_jh.C4.81nas)
- [Seven stages of purification](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/mahasi/progress.html)
- [Seven stages of mind training](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lojong) (in Tibetan Buddhism)

Also: Happy birthday!

Comment: Great answer! Along the same thoughts I had when looking at the question!